# Django Models: Inline has no ForeignKey to

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have read a few of these question on stack already but I can't get my desired results.

I have a simple `models.Model` class, named `Driftwood()` in an app named `driftwoods`. In another app `galleries` I have the model `GalleryPiece` which uses a `Driftwood()` `ForeginKey()`.

I could make `Driftwood()` have a `ForiegnKey()` to a `GalleryPiece()`, which by looking at other code samples should work. But I was wanting to reuse my `Driftwood()` model in a store app, using a `ForeingKey()` the same way I do in `GalleryPiece()`, but with not to ties to the `galleries` app.

Is this possible or do I have to make a `GalleryDriftwood()` and a `ProductDriftwood()` model? I know this makes more sense but I would perfer all my `Driftwood()` to be in one table.

#### myproject/driftwoods/models.py

```
class Size( models.Model ):
    length = models.IntegerField()
    width  = models.IntegerField()
    height = models.IntegerField()

class Driftwood( models.Model ):
    name            = models.CharField( max_length=60, default='driftwood' )
    weight          = models.FloatField()
    size            = models.ForeignKey( Size )
    image           = models.ImageField( upload_to='static/driftwoods/' )
```

#### myproject/galleries/models.py

```
from driftwoods.models import Driftwood

class Gallary( models.Model ):
    name            = models.CharField( max_length=60 )
    image           = models.ImageField( upload_to='static/galleries/' )


class GallaryPiece( models.Model ):
    name            = models.CharField( max_length=60 )
    gallary         = models.ForeignKey( Gallary )
    driftwood       = models.ForeignKey( Driftwood )
```

I was going to use the store app like so.

```
from driftwoods.models import Driftwood

class Product( models.Model ):
    driftwood = models.ForeignKey( Driftwood )
    price     = models.FloatField()
```

The only way I have of adding a `Driftwood()` model is through an `TabularInline` class in `gallaries/admin.py`.

#### myproject/driftwoods/admin.py

```
# NOTHING, ADD DRIFTWOOD BY CREATING A GALLEY PIECE
```

#### myproject/galleries/admin.py

```
from driftwoods.models import Driftwood

class DriftwoodInline( admin.TabularInline ):
    model = Driftwood


class GallaryAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin ):
    fieldsets = [
            (None,                  {'fields': ['name']} ),
            ('Date Information',    {'fields': ['pub_date']} ),
            ('Gallary Image',       {'fields': ['image']} ),
    ]


class GallaryPieceAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin ):
    fieldsets = [
            (None,                  {'fields': ['name']} ),
            ('Date Information',    {'fields': ['pub_date']} ),
            ('Description',         {'fields': ['description']} ),
    ]
    inlines = [DriftwoodInline]


admin.site.register( Gallary, GallaryAdmin )
admin.site.register( GallaryPiece, GallaryPieceAdmin )
```

P.S Im going on a boat right now, so I will be back in about 2-3 hours to pick an answer. As always I appreciate the help (Who doesn't).

Comment: Hopefully the following post should offer some insight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390627/how-can-i-display-a-django-admin-inline-model-within-a-fieldset

P.S I'd recommend you take a look at [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008). More complex code written in the same fashion as you've posted can become very difficult for others to read :)

Comment: I have been meany to read the pep guidelines, now that some one has recommended it, It will move up on my to do list.